# Setting up Xdebug with Docker Compose and WordPress image

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, xdebug

I am trying to set up Xdebug with docker-compose. I'm using PhpStorm IDE and the Docker image I'm using installs PHP 7.2. I'm trying to do this within the context of this WordPress image. Here is my current docker-compose.yml file:

```
    version: '3'

    services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     ports: 
       - "3306:3306"
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   web-build-scripts:
     build: .
     depends_on:
       - db
     ports:
       - "8028:80"
       - "8029:8029"

     volumes:
       - ./themes/XXXXX:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/XXXX
       - ./plugins/XXXX:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/XXXXX
       - ./plugins/XXXXX:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/XXXXX
       - ./plugins/XXXXX:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/XXXXX
       - ./plugins/XXXXX:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/XXXXX
       - ./plugins/XXXXX:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/XXXXX
       - ./plugins/XXXXX:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/XXXXX
       - ./plugins/XXXXX:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/XXXXX
       - ./plugins/XXXXX:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/XXXXX


     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       VIRTUAL_HOST: leasepilot.local

volumes:
    db_data:
```

Then my Dockerfile which I have tagged as web-build-scripts (and built of course) looks like this:

```
FROM wordpress:latest

WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN pecl install xdebug-2.6.0 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install nano \
    && export TERM=xterm

COPY Search-Replace-DB/ ./wp-content/Search-Replace-DB/
COPY uploads/ ./wp-content/uploads/
COPY ./docker-config/xdebug.ini ../../../usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

Where my xdebug.ini file that is within my docker-config directory locally looks like so:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTR
xdebug.remote_host = docker.for.mac.internal
```

Within PHPStorm I have set the debug settings like so:
[image]
And I have set up the server mapping like so:
[image]

I have also set the Debug Port to 9001 as I did in my xdebug.ini file:
[image]

When I run the command php -ini | grep xdebug my output is as follows:

```
root@a96543427809:/var/www/html# php -ini | grep xdebug
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
xdebug
xdebug support => enabled
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => PHPSTR => PHPSTR
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => 2 => 2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => On => On
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => docker.for.mac.internal => docker.for.mac.internal
xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9001 => 9001
xdebug.remote_timeout => 200 => 200
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

I've gone through several tutorials and haven't been able to figure this out. Anyone hav any insights that may help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What i would do

- First you are using `wordpress:latest` so you have to find which php
  version your wordpress image is running.
- Then check is `xdebug` is installed in the container. Most probably not!
- Create a `Dockerfile` with `xdebug` installation for the development, dont use this for production, it will slow down your performance.
- Build *your-wordpress* image from that `Dockerfile`.
- You might need to create the `xdebug.ini` file with your remote host details, i'm using phpstrom this is what my `xdebug.ini` looks like. I keep this file in my host machine and copy it with `volumes`.

> ```
> zend_extension=xdebug.so
> xdebug.remote_enable=1
> xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
> xdebug.remote_port=10000 # dont use 9000 its usually used by the php-fpm
> xdebug.remote_autostart=1
> xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
> xdebug.idekey=PHPSTRM
> xdebug.remote_host=host-ip-here
> ```

This is how my docker-compose file looks like

> ```
> version: '2'
> services:
>     my-service:
>         build:
>           context: ./dev
>           dockerfile: Dockerfile
>         ports:
>             - "8080:80"
>         restart: always
>         environment:
>             - RUNTIME_ENVIRONMENT=local
>         working_dir: /src
>         volumes:
>             - ./src:/src
>             - ./php-ini-overrides-dev.ini/xdebug.ini:/etc/php/7.1/mods-available/xdebug.ini
> ```

- Then configure phpstorm remote debugging with `xdebug.ini` details.
- To make sure xdebug config loaded, log into container and run `php -ini | grep xdebug`
- This is one way of getting `xdebug` works.
- If its not working enable xdebug log, add `xdebug.remote_log=/log_path/xdebug.log` to xdebug.ini will help to diagnose the issue.
- Let me know if you also need help with setuping the phpstorm remote debugging. Actually there are lots of resources out there.

Comment: @ Ntwobike I have edited my answer, based on some stuff you suggested but I still can't get the code to stop at any point! Do you have any further advice?

Comment: Try setting the port in phpstorm. Language framework -> PHP-> Debug in the Xdebug section set the Debug port to 9001 Also a small note i only use PHP Remote Debugging not the PHP Web Page

Comment: @ Ntwobike I went ahead and switched to PHP remote Debug with and without the Filter debug connection (with the key PHPSTR that I have in my xdebug.ini file). I'm thinking that I'm placing my xdebug.ini file in the wrong spot?

Comment: Yep it could be, log into the container and check `php -ini | grep xdebug` if you dont see the xdebug details then its not loaded

Comment: @ Ntwobike it looks like my configuration are being loaded in (see my edits).... I guess the next place to look is how I am setting up my paths. It should be noted that I'm loading my theme through volumes... don't really know why that would matter.

Comment: what i would do enable xdebug log. add this to xdebug.ini `xdebug.remote_log=/log_path/xdebug.log` then you can see what its trying to do

Comment: @ Ntwobike I'm looking into this now but all it prints out is:
I: Connecting to configured address/port: docker.for.mac.internal:9002.
W: Creating socket for 'docker.for.mac.internal:9002', getaddrinfo: Success.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2018-11-30 16:20:05

Comment: I also started out with port 9001 and switched to port 9002 in hopes that this would be the issue but apparently its not.

Comment: try to get the ip from here and hardcode it in the xdebug.ini `docker run -it alpine nslookup docker.for.mac.localhost`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184526/discussion-between-ntwobike-and-david-jarrin).

Comment: @ Ntwobike you sir are a saint, that was it, I had to hard code in the IP and things seemed to work (I also allow for PHPstorm to Filter debug connection by IDK key).

Comment: Note: you can use `host.docker.internal` as `remote_host`
https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-714253414

Answer (score 3):

@david-jarrin,

Looking at your `php -ini` output, it looks like your XDebug is already running. Could it be installing (and activating) a never version, version 3.x instead of the 2.x you've specified? That was the grief in my case.

Please note that version 3 of XDebug has introduced a **fair amount of config name changes that are not backwards compatible**. There's an [upgrade guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) available. You'll find that various config keys have changed, including ones that are vital in running XDebug from a Docker container.

I'm using the official Wordpress Docker image just as you are, and it took a while to dig up the reason why suddenly xdebug.remote_host doesn't work anymore, and why my logs aren't showing up. It's all in the upgrade guide.

This is a basic config that works for me, when using VS Code with [felixbecker's XDebug extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug).

You can include the xdebug install in your Dockerfile. This actually runs a custom function inside the php container that the Wordpress container is using, `docker-php-ext-enable`. Use the Dockerfile to build your XDebug-enabled version of the Wordpress container:

```
FROM wordpress:latest

RUN pecl install "xdebug" \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

Create an xdebug.ini file in a folder relative to your `docker-compose.yml` file, like `./conf/xdebug.ini` for example:

```
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.client_port=9000
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.log_level=7
xdebug.log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey=sts-debug
xdebug.max_nesting_level=1500
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms=60000
```

It's more flexible to inject the xdebug config like this in your `docker-compose.yml` file, that way you don't have to rebuild your image every time you change your xdebug config.

```
wordpress:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: custom-wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - './:/var/www/html'
      - ./conf/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

Happy trails!

Answer (score 0):

Need to see what network the container is using and setting the correctly ingress network in your xdebug.ini.

$ docker network inspect <your-network>

> "Peers": [
> {
> "Name": "6ecc2369ba2f",
> "IP": "172.17.49.56"
> }
> ]

And then setting the IP in your xdebug.ini
`xdebug.client_host=<IP>`