# Docker Compose and Xdebug not working in PhpStorm

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, phpstorm, xdebug

I've tried many things trying to let work Xdebug in a Docker container. I came in contact with these resources:

- [Setting up Xdebug with Docker Compose and WordPress image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52995837/setting-up-xdebug-with-docker-compose-and-wordpress-image/52998150)
- [Installing XDebug in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49907308/installing-xdebug-in-docker)
- [Starting The Debugger](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote#starting)
- [Zero-configuration Web Application Debugging with Xdebug and PhpStorm](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm)
- [Xdebug & Zend Debugger bookmarklets generator for PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/)
- [Configure Xdebug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html)
- [Troubleshooting common PHP debugging issues](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html)
- .. and other

I think the problem is either something with the ports that I don't understand, or it is something with the debugger session not being started or recognized. For the debugger session I have also tried to install a browser extension that sets a cookie.

I ended up at least to have separate containers, one as dev container with enabled Xdebug.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  production:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
  development:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
#      - "10000:80" also not working
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./dev.php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4.0-apache

RUN pecl install xdebug \
  && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

**dev.php.ini**

```
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_port=10000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

**localhost:8080 phpinfo data**

[image]

[image]

**PhpStorm config**

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I think your issue is the `remote_host`,  this host is the debug client's IP, your host.  And  don't think host.docker.internal is being resolved as your host IP, there was a Docker feature request open for linux and think they haven't release a fix or improve this.

Comment: 1) `xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal` will work only if your host OS is Windows or Mac -- https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264. On Linux you need to locate your host IP address yourself (e.g. `ip addr` and look for `docker0` entry) 2) `#      - "10000:80" also not working` -- will not work. This way you forward incoming connection from your OS into a container. But it's wrong .. as it's Xdebug that connects to IDE and NOT other way around. So it's IDE that listens on Xdebug port.. and if it's already used by Docker then no connection is possible.

Comment: 3) https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2018/08/quickstart-with-docker-in-phpstorm/

Comment: @abestrad Actually i am using Docker Desktop (for Windows), and i saw this usage in on another working example

Comment: @LazyOne 1) I am using Docker Desktop (for Windows). 2) Thanks for this explanation. 3) Good to know there is this quickstart article, but i dont need it aymore, guess what was the solution, a PC restart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After booting up my machine to investigate further with the comments of @abestrad and @LazyOne, without changing anything, opening localhost:8080 suddenly let the debugging work by stopping at the breakpoint that I have set. Actually I had already tried to restart the Docker Desktop App before writing the question, maybe at that point my configurations were at a wrong state.

But at the end the solution was: **Restarting the PC**.

**Watch out**

To be sure i tried to open it also in a private browser session and it wasn't working anymore. That was because the special cookie still was set in the normal browser store (cookie that was stored either from the Browser extension that I have already uninstalled, or from trying out the [JetBrains Bookmarklets generator](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/) before writing the question).

The solution to let it work everytime was to add following:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

Citate from [here](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote#starting):

> Normally you need to use a specific HTTP GET/POST variable to start remote debugging (see Step Debugging). When this setting is set to 1, Xdebug will always attempt to start a remote debugging session and try to connect to a client, even if the GET/POST/COOKIE variable was not present.

Comment: `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` It can be quite inconvenient to have it permanently enabled... I suggest to use Xdebug browser extension (that sets Xdebug cookie) -- it works just fine and you have full control over when to start and when to stop.

Comment: Do you have an example use case of the inconvenience? I dont want do load another addon into my browser, and the alternative, sending that variable separately in another way, seems inconvenient to me. If i want dev mode without x debug, i could also define another container for that.

Comment: It will attempt to debug every single script. Imagine some Ajax request that may be running in background or scheduled task etc. It's all up to you of course. Maybe your project/setup does not have such extensive setup so will simply not face it at all.